# RAZOR - how to pass data to controller using Url.Action?

Tags: razor, url.action

I have page which display a table and a DropDownList - which are not included in the form.
When a user selects a value in the DropDownList - JavaSript puts the selected value in a text box named selectedCategory which is located in a form:

```
@Html.TextBox("selectedCategory", null, new { @id = "selectedCategory", @style = "width: 100px;" })
```

I am using paging, so I have:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
new { page, SortO = ViewBag.SortO, 
      FilterV = ViewBag.FilterV, 
      category = selectedCategory  }))
```

In this case I am getting error:
*The name 'selectedCategory' does not exist in the current context.*
When I run **without** "category = selectedCategory  " on the page source I see the field exists:

```
<input id="selectedCategory" name="selectedCategory" style="width: 100px;" type="text" value="" />
```

So my question is how to add "category = value of selectedCategory field" ?

Thanks,

zb

Answer (score 0):

I analysed my problem again and I come to conclusion that I need to solve my problem different way - using Session variables or ViewBag.

And here is why:
The code:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
new { page, SortO = ViewBag.SortO, 
      FilterV = ViewBag.FilterV, 
      category = xxx  }))
```

is converted to HTML:

```
<li><a href="/?page=2&SortO=My%20Sort&FilterV=My%20Filter&category=xxx">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/?page=3&SortO=My%20Sort&FilterV=My%20Filter&category=xxx">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="/?page=4&SortO=My%20Sort&FilterV=My%20Filter&category=xxx">4</a></li>
```

After user selects an option from the DropDownList, a JavaScript function will need to update "category=xxx" with value of the selected option - I think it can be done, but it looks to convoluted to me.